# How to define CRUD policy in SAM (Serverless application model) template to more than one table for a lambda functio?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-cloudformation, serverless-application-model

I am using SAM (Serverless application model) and creating policy for lambda function for dynamo. By default **AmazonDynamoDBFullAccess** is there but I want to give **DynamoDBCrudPolicy** for lambda function in which more than one table is used.

In aws sam docs there is policy for one table not for more than one

```
Policies:
      # Give just CRUD permissions to one table
      - DynamoDBCrudPolicy:
          TableName: !Ref MyTable
```

Here is CRUD policy for one table, I want for more  than one table.

Answer (score 11):

You could include several policies, one for each table, or provide a `"*"` for all DDB tables (note that `"*"` provides much broader permissions than is recommended, though).

```
    Policies:
      # Give just CRUD permissions to one table
      - DynamoDBCrudPolicy:
          TableName: !Ref MyTable
      # Give just CRUD permissions to another table
      - DynamoDBCrudPolicy:
          TableName: !Ref MyOtherTable
      # Give just CRUD permissions to all tables
      - DynamoDBCrudPolicy:
          TableName: "*"
```

Comment: This MyOtherTable solution is not currently working for me. The '*' work around works but isn't great security wise. Anytime I have 2 DynamoDBCrudPolicy lines I get these errors: "Must specify valid parameter values for policy template 'DynamoDBCrudPolicy'" Anyone else experiencing this?